# Redirect to User friendly Error page for Unauthorized users

Tags: java, angular

I am using angular2 and Java technologies for my application. The Angular part was merged with java. Now I would like to create an user friendly error page for unauthorized users.The application was running on Liberty. I have already tried few things as follows:

1. Used error-page tag in web.xml.But it doesn't work. For unauthorized users, the full stack of exception is getting displayed but not the error page which I mentioned in the location tag.
2. Used SSOFilter but this gets worked in local but not on the remote environments.

So could you please provide some information on this of how can I meet my requirement.

Comment: @Meno there is nothing as Angular2. Its just angular

Comment: @TavishAggarwal The original question points to "angular2" so I didn't want to change it. And please see also [following article](http://eisenbergeffect.bluespire.com/all-about-angular-2-0/) about angular versioning which clearly mentions angular2 (which for you is just angular).

Comment: @MenoHochschild The link you have shared is not from google. Please let me know if google calls Angular as Angular2.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your structure can be:

```
  const routes: Routes = [
        { path: '', component: LandingComponent },
        { path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: '404' }
    ];
```

`path ''` ->  means any path;

`path '**'` -> refers to an invalid page